# Updating or Deleting a record from a link in Email

Tags: email-template, update, delete

The use case is - A subscriber (contact) is sent an email regarding a specific product to which he's subscribed to. At the end of the email is "Unsubscribe" button through which he can unsubscribe.

On clicking on the button I'm need to either update a record or delete a record or do both (on different objects)

I'm still not sure what I'm going to be using for sending emails (Salesforce templates or Mail chimp) but I'm just wondering if this is possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MailChimp, you can sync with their unsubscribes as described here: http://blog.mailchimp.com/salesforce-unsubscribe/

Comment: I suppose I can change the logic of updating the Contact / Lead object. For the current requirements - unsubscribe feature is applicable to multiple products that the contact has subscribed. So it will be stored in another junction object. And there is where I may need to update the subscription...

Answer (score 1):

I have used this AppExchange product 'Unsubscribe/opt-out' from SFDC Labs at https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YDZEA2  successfully

Customization details are here: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P30000003TbeGEAS

Essentially, you are creating a mailto link on the customer's email where if they click said link, an SFDC Inbound Email service is invoked with the email address of the sender as well as an instruction as to what to do (unsubscribe, for example)

[image]

Comment: This can be used with Leads object, I don't see any way to customize it for a custom object. If you have any idea let me know. I need to update a custom object on "Unsubscribe"

Comment: do you still need an answer here? I see you accepted Daniel's response.  As this is an apex inbound email handler, it can readily be adapted through apex programming to custom objects